Was the Ethiopian eunuch a proselyte or a Gentile sympathizer?
27 So he got ready and went; and there was an Ethiopian eunuch, a court official of Candace, queen of the Ethiopians, who was in charge of all her treasure; and he had come to Jerusalem to worship, 28 and he was returning and sitting in his chariot, and was reading Isaiah the prophet. (Acts 8:27-29, NASB 2020)
Question #1
Given the definitions below and assuming those are accurate, how can we ascertain whether the Ethiopian eunuch was a proselyte or just a devout, God-fearing man (Gentile sympathizer)?

If a Proselyte, how do we reconcile this with the fact that this would require the Ethiopian to get circumcised to convert to Judaism, which he could not, considering his physical condition?
If a Gentile sympathizer, how do we reconcile this with Acts 10 account where Cornelius is assumed to be the first Gentile converted to Christianity? Peter's initial reluctance to visit him (Acts 10:28) demonstrates that Cornelius was considered to be a Gentile sympathizer.

Question #2
Where in the NT can we identify unequivocally a Gentile sympathizer who is not actually a proselyte?
Cornelius seems to be a good example as he is described as a "God-fearer" but is still considered a Gentile, as evidenced by Peter's initial reluctance to visit him: 28 And he said to them, “You yourselves know that it is forbidden for a Jewish man to associate with or visit a foreigner; and yet God has shown me that I am not to call any person unholy or unclean. (Acts 10:28)
Definitions

Jews refers to those who were ethnically and religiously Jewish by birth and heritage (children of Abraham/house of Israel).
Gloss: Jewish (people), Jewish
https://www.billmounce.com/greek-dictionary/ioudaios

Jews from the diaspora (or of the dispersion) refers to those living outside of their ancestral homeland (the land of Israel), regardless of where they were born.
Gloss: scattering, dispersion, Diaspora
https://www.billmounce.com/greek-dictionary/diaspora

Proselytes refers to those who were not born Jewish (Gentile) but had converted to the Jewish faith (Judaism) by being circumcised (if male) and committing to follow Jewish law and customs.
Gloss: Gentile convert (to Judaism), transliterated as proselyte
https://www.billmounce.com/greek-dictionary/proselytos

Worshipers, or Devout and God-Fearing People refers to Gentiles who admired Judaism (Gentile sympathizers) and followed some practices, but did not fully convert.
Gloss: (mid.) to worship, be devout, God-fearing
https://www.billmounce.com/greek-dictionary/sebo



Why do you discard the possibility that the eunuch was a Jew of the diaspora?

A eunuch can be circumcised.  An emasculated male cannot be circumcised.  He was, most probably, a Jew from diaspora.  However, we are not told so we do not know.

@user111403 Good point. I should have included that possiblity. An oversight on my end. Thank you.

Question 1

Eunuchs are capable of circumcision since the definition of a eunuch is "one who has been castrated" not "one whose penis has been cut off." Also Isaiah guarantees that a eunuch may be accepted into Israel:

Isaiah 56

The foreigner joined to the Lord should not say,
“The Lord will surely exclude me from his people”; Nor should the eunuch say,
“See, I am a dry tree.” 4  For thus says the Lord: To the eunuchs who keep my sabbaths,
who choose what pleases me,
and who hold fast to my covenant, 5 I will give them, in my house
and within my walls, a monument and a name Better than sons and daughters;
an eternal name, which shall not be cut off, will I give them.


Nevertheless, Cornelius does not seem to be a full proselyte, or he would keep kosher and Peter should have no problem entering his house. Not certain what the OP means by "Peter's utter amazement." As I read it, it is the Jewish Christians who accompany Peter that are amazed, not Peter himself. They are amazed because this is the first time in their experience that non-Jews received the Holy Spirit.

Question 2
Cornelius himself is a good example of a Gentile sympathizer who is not a full proselyte. Another example is found in Luke 7:5, where a local centurion is described as a man who "loves our nation and he built the synagogue for us.” There are several other references to Gentiles who attend local synagogues but it is not clear to me whether they are God-fearers of actual proselytes. Personally, I do not believe that Jews necessarily made a strict distinction between the two, as many Jews were not fully observant, just as is the case today.

I changed the wording to try to clarify "Peter's utter amazement."

Pertinent InformationThere is limited information given by the Scriptures concerning this gentleman:

He was an Ethiopian (black native, or Jewish naturalized immigrant ?)
He  was a eunuch (by court order, or natural accident?)
He was Minister of the Treasury of the Queen of Ethiopia (Exchequer?)
He was familiar with Temple worship in Jerusalem (holy day observer, or ordinary pilgrim?)
He was familiar with the Tanakh.
He was not a disciple of the strict rabbinical schools (Pharisees, Sadducees, etc.) who rejected Jesus out of hand; but was open to considering Jesus as Messiah.
He was familiar with the rite of baptism (rabbinical mitvah, John's baptism?)

Beyond these, we can only speculate. There are no definitive statements that can provide a certain answer to this posted question.
This Treasurer may have followed in the footsteps of the great prophet/administrator, Daniel: a relocated Jew influencing his new homeland. Or he was simply an Ethiopian native convert---to some degree or another, proselyte or God-fearer---who wished to make a pilgrimage to Jerusalem.
But the greatest fact we are sure of: He is now a brother in Christ in the family of God! Circumcised or not, eunuch notwithstanding, Jewish native or Gentile...are all superfluous points of discussion. He is a Christian!

Great analysis and fair conclusion. Thank you. Question regarding bullet point #7: is it possible that he learned about baptism from Philip?

@ TruthSeeker - Yes, it is possible. What is interesting is that HE asked to be baptized! Any way, he realized the importance of it as a requirement for initiation into the Church; and Philip may have emphasized that,  or referred to John's teaching as a foundation of discipleship, with a new meaning introduced by Jesus.
